# Deprecated CSVWriter constructor

Tags: java, opencsv

I am using [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to create CSV files filled with records from database. I am using this:

```
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("example.csv"),
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8), ';');
```

The problem is, this constructor is `@Deprecated`.

The library has several constructors, but only one is not deprecated. I am using this constructor:

```
/** @deprecated */
@Deprecated
public CSVWriter(Writer writer, char separator) {
    this(writer, separator, '"');
}
```

while I should be using this:

```
public CSVWriter(Writer writer, char separator, char quotechar, char escapechar, String lineEnd) {
    super(writer, lineEnd);
    this.escapechar = escapechar;
    this.quotechar = quotechar;
    this.separator = separator;
}
```

But I am not exactly sure what to put in there as I do not want my files to end up different.

Comment: go through the documentation. no doubt the deprecated comment explains which alternative to use and how

Comment: so look at what the default values are for the other values, and pass those. But why not taking advantage of the additional options?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The class already has static fields which represent the defaults, so you can simply do:

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("example.csv"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
    ';',
    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,
    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the same constructor with default values:

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(SAZKOVA_UDALOST),
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8), ';', '"', '"', "\n");
```

> Default value for `separator` is `;`. Default value for `quotechar` is
>   `"`. Default value for `escapechar` is `"`. Default value for
>   `lineEnd` is `"\n"`.